# Android Test in Andrios Studio gives INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

When running an Android Test from Android Studio I always get:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE]
```

This happens even if I have uninstalled the app or created a fresh virtual device.

Any idea what this is and how to solve it?

Comment: Please post the information that's shown in logcat when it tries to install the APK. That may shed a little more light on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also getting this same error on a fresh install when testing in Android Studio.  In my case I changed the name of the testPackageName.  This was the same as the default package name.

Now the tests are running smoothly.  I don't know why it worked but it did.  Increasing the versionCode should have worked but it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

`INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE` means that the app installed on the device/simulator has **lower** `versionCode` that the build you are trying to install. You need to uninstall it first, or bump `versionCode`

Comment: To repeat: "This happens even if I have uninstalled the app or created a fresh virtual device." Also if I bump the version number.

Comment: do you by any chance got other devices connected aside simulator? because that would be extremely odd to see INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE if there's no such package installed at all

Comment: Yes, the Android Test works on the phone. And it works when I run the Android Application, both in emulator and on device. It is only when I run the Android Test on an emulator I get the problem.

Comment: In my case, the computer was connected to one emulator without the app and one device with a newer app. I can test on the emulator after disconnecting the device